# Hilt - How to inject an object based on some value using @AssistedInject

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm attempting to use `@AssistedInject`to inject some object into my ViewModel based on some key. The object I want to use is an object also constructed via Hilt. I want to know what the best practice for this is. Below I have included an example of what im trying to achieve. Can I do this without the key, but actual object I want to use?

For Example:

```
class Test @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted key: String
): ViewModel() {
    lateinit var someInterface: SomeInterface
    
    init {
        when (key) {
            "Example" -> Implementation instance // how to get this hilt instance? 
            "Other" -> OtherImplementation instance // how to get this hilt instance? 
        }
    }
}

//Assited Inject setup
boiler plate

interface SomeInterface {
    fun get()
}

class Implementation @Inject constructor(
    val repository: Repository
): SomeInterface {
    override fun get() {
        repository.get()
    }
}

other implementations: etc....
```